# Execution trouble with wp_set_post_terms

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to Set value for my posts taxonomy.

This is my function:

```
function test( $alan )
{
    global $post;    
    $ozel = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "".$alan."", true );    
    $comp = floatval( get_post_meta( $post->ID, "".$alan."", true ));    

    if ( (float) $comp > 7.0 )
    {    
        return wp_set_post_terms( $post->ID,"MY TITLE DOCUMENTATION", my_taxonomy);
    }

    return false;
}
```

This function will check the float of a custom field (text) and will insert tags in `my_taxonomy`, but I don't know how to execute it just one time.

ps: the code was on `single.php` file

Comment: To execute this code once, put it in your theme's functions.php file. Then make the call to your function in single.php. Then remove the call from single.php after you'ved visited a single blog page on your site.

Comment: Hi henry , thanks for the reply :)
i'want to applay this to all my posts not a single one !!

Comment: Ah OK! See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You could try hooking to the `wp_insert_post` action, making use of `$update` to see if the post is being created or updated. For example:

```
function test( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
    if ( ! $update ) {
        global $post;    
        $ozel = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "".$alan."", true );    
        $comp = floatval( get_post_meta( $post->ID, "".$alan."", true ));    

        if ( (float) $comp > 7.0 )  
            return wp_set_post_terms( $post->ID,"MY TITLE DOCUMENTATION", my_taxonomy);

        return false;
    } else {
        // Do nothing because this is a post update.
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'test', 10, 3 );
```

Note: I'm not sure how you're getting the `$alan` variable. You'll have to add that into my code above for it to work.